# Cassandra big table migration bottleneck

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, data-migration, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to migrate big table in cassandra to new empty table (with different primary key), in the same keyspace and cluster, by using spark 1.2.1:

```
val rdd_table_a = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table_a").filter(row => row.getLong("a") >= start_a && row.getLong("a") <= end_a)

    rdd_table_a.map(row => { 
        val a = row.getLong("a")
        val b = row.getLong("b")
        val c = row.getString("c")
        val d = row.getString("d")
        val new_a = generateSomeNewValue(a)
        connector.withSessionDo(session => {
            val statement = session.prepare(s"INSERT INTO keyspace.table_b (new_a, c, b, a, d) " + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
            val bound = statement.bind(new_a, c, b, a, d)
            session.executeAsync(bound)
        })
    }).foreach(x => x.getUninterruptibly())
```

The table have more then 1B rows and even when I trying to process small part of it- it takes **more then 7 hours**. 
I searched in the documentation and didn't find- is connector.withSessionDo open in each loop iteration another session?

What can be the **bottleneck** in above code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conn.withSessionDo` executes custom CQL query using current shared connection to Cassandra:

> Allows to use Cassandra `Session` in a safe way without  risk of forgetting to close it. The `Session` object obtained through this method is a proxy to a shared, single `Session` associated with the cluster.
>
> Internally, the shared underlying `Session` will be closed shortly after all the proxies are closed.

You can rewrite your code using `saveToCassandra` approach which is more typical.

As for my personal experience working with Spark+Cassandra, the slowest point for such queries is the Cassandra itself: data scans for huge tables are really slow (compared to Parquet).

Comment: @shutty- why should I use saveToCassandra? I would need to generate a class object each loop for each row: case class table_b_row(a: String, b: Long, c: String, d: Long, a_new: Long); and push to cassandra: collection.saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table_b", SomeColumns("a", "b","c", "d","a_new")); How is it better for my case?

Comment: For readability and further core maintenance by other people. Before discussing any performance problems (and rewriting your code in a "more efficient way"), do actual measurements. I bet that creating/deleting a new case class will take less than 1/1000 of time needed for writing it into Cassandra.